How to read variable starting with numbers in R
I am using getSymbols("0700.hk") to fetch the historical closing prices of 700HK. This creates an XTS table in my global environment 0700.HK, if I call that table directly I get:
> View(0700.HK)
Error: unexpected symbol in "View(0700.HK"

To make it work I need to use:
> View(`0700.HK`)

.blotter$portfolio$symbols$700.HK$txn`    # would not work, but: 
.blotter$portfolio$symbols$`700.HK`$txn`  # would work.

I remember there was a way to make it possible for R to recognize variable starting with numbers, does someone know the trick please?

get("0700.HK")?

Yes, I get use that too,  but I am trying to find a long term solution so that package like Blotter can work without me tricking them  manually. for example: .blotter$portfolio$symbols$700.HK$txn would not work, but :
.blotter$portfolio$symbols$700.HK$txn would work.

You could rename everything by adding a fixed prefix.

If you're concerned about getting variables that are nested, $ is just a faster way or doing [[ ]] so you can can just use .blotter$portfolio$symbols[["0700.HK"]]$txn. Or even, purrr::pluck(.blotter, "portfolio", "symbols", "0700.HK", "txn"). Also, there is not a way to use a variable starting with a number without backticks (see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic or https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f)

There's no way to change the R parser to allow for variable names that start with numbers. That's simply not allowed by the language definition. You simply have to use the escaping tricks you've already shows to use invalid variable names.

Strange, I remember I was able to do it before we did this major system upgrade and had to reinstall everything.  All good, I use some of the suggestions you guys made. Thank you!
